# SQL server Like pattern match with CONCAT() always fails

Tags: sql-server, where, concat, like

I am facing problem in a simple query script for SQL server. Please help

The script is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search_By_Author_And_Name] 
(
    @Author_name AS [varchar](50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    Select B.*, R.R_number From Book AS B , Rack As R
    where B.Author LIKE CONCAT('%', @Author_name, '%')
    AND B.B_Id=R.B_Id
END 
GO
```

The problem is this returns no columns. Even if I pass a valid argument(@Author_name) to the procedure it returns nothing. There must be a problem in the where clause in the usage of LIKE.

sample data in the table are

[image]

the first table is Book table and the other table is Rack table

I am calling the procedure by

```
EXEC Search_By_Author_And_Name 'Physics'
```

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are there any rows in Rack?

Comment: Yes there are rows in Rack

Comment: What version of SQL?  I am running this same scenario on 2014, and it works as expected.

Comment: Why not just have Like '%' + @Author_name + '%'. Also, use JOIN to join the 2 tables and not the implied join ","

Comment: @WEI_DBA that dosent work either

Comment: Can you show data from both tables and expected results? Also show what you are passing into the proc.

Comment: You must have a data issue, or perhaps a collation (Case Sensetive??) issue.  This should work (I am ignoring the Cartesian product, I assume you meant to do it)

Comment: I added additional information in the question

Comment: Try 'Physics'...You may have a case sensitive collation

Comment: Ya that was a mistake....but it dosent work now also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only matching on Author, not B_Name.  Change code to:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search_By_Author_And_Name] 
(
    @Author_name AS [varchar](50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    Select B.*, R.R_number From Book AS B , Rack As R
    where (B.Author LIKE CONCAT('%', @Author_name, '%') OR
    B.B_Name LIKE CONCAT('%', @Author_name, '%'))
    AND B.B_Id=R.B_Id
END 
GO
```

Comment: Ya i changed that..bt still it dosent work

Comment: You are matching on Author, not B_NAME

Comment: pass in the value 'hc'

Comment: Needs parentheses around the `OR` conditions.